# xsd reusing of complex type in a different namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

I have 2 xsd's belonging to 2 different namespace's. is it possible for me to reference a complex type as an element in a xsd from a different namespance and add on child elements to it ?

Global.xsd - namespace - Namespace

```
<xs:complexType name = "body" mixed="true">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="fontStyle" type="fontStyle"/>
        <xs:element name="link" type="link"/>
        <xs:element name="mark" type="mark"/>
        <xs:element name="orderedList" type="orderedList"/>
        <xs:element name="table" type="table"/>
        <xs:element name="toc" type="toc"/>
        <xs:element name="unorderedList" type="unorderedList"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

test.xsd namespace - test

```
<xs:element name="body" type="n:body"/>
```

- is it possible for me to add child elements???

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not. Something like:

```
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="urn:m"
    xmlns:m="urn:m"
    xmlns:n="urn:n"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="urn:n" schemaLocation="n.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="body" type="n:body"/>

    <xsd:element name="extendedBody" type="m:extendedBody"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="extendedBody">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="n:body">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="additionalElement" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

However mind that XML will be like:

```
<m:extendedBody>
    <n:toc>...</n:toc>
    <m:additionalElement>...</m:additionalElement>
</m:extendedBody>
```

(I have not checked the solution though, this is only to give an idea. Quite probable that mixed/choice extension won't work.)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you just need to extend the type like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="moreBodyType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="n:body">
            <xs:sequence>
                // put extra child elements here
                                   <xs:element name="morestuff" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

So now you can do:

```
<xs:element name="morebody" type="n:MoreBodyType" />
```